# Only get the main folders and no subfolders

Tags: php, directory, subdirectory, recursiveiterator

I want to get the main folder with no subfolders with the following code:

```
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($admin['data_folder_main'], FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$it->setMaxDepth(1);

foreach($it AS $fileinfo) {
    if($fileinfo->isDir() AND !$it->isDot()) {
        echo $it->getSubPathName().'<br>';
    }
}
```

As it is right now, this code prints

```
main-folder
main-folder/subfolder
main-folder/subfolder
```

Does `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` or `RecursiveIteratorIterator` have a function that says that "this is the main folder"? Or do I have to use some workaround code? If yes, how will that code look like?

Comment: Why are you using a recursive iterator when you're only interested in the first level? Could you give an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I fixed it like this:

```
$dir = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($admin['data_folder_main']), FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($dir as $name => $object) {
    if($dir->isDir() AND !$dir->isDot()) {
        echo basename($name);
    }
}
```